# Hostname resolution with .local suffix

Tags: networking

Previously, I was able to resolve the ip address of machines on my local network using just "hostname" (where "hostname" is the name of the machine). For some reason, it seems that I can no longer resolve the address of machines without adding the ".local" suffix.

If I try "ping hostname", I get "could not find host...", but if I try "ping hostname.local" the machine is pinged as expected.

This seems to happen on every machine on my network. I have checked all the hostnames and none of them have ".local" appended to them. Also, the hostnames all will resolve with just "hostname" if I try to ping the machine that I am currently on.

As far as I know, nothing has changed on my network. Does anyone know what the cause of this could be? Could there be a network-wide issue or does this sound like an issue on a per-machine basis? The machines that I have tried are running Windows, OS X, and Debian. The router that I am using is a Netgear R7000.

Comment: This exact same thing just happened on my local network after my ISP decided to "upgrade" my Sagemcom router firmware. But alas, no answers yet...

Answer (score 0):

I never figured out what changed that caused this but my best guess is that at some point my router stopped including `.local` as a search domain for machines that were configured via DHCP. I just started using `hostname.local` to connect to other local machines.

However, there is a fix if you want your local hosts to be resolvable without `.local`. Just go into each machine's DNS settings and add `.local` as a search domain. Or, if your router supports it, add `.local` as a search domain in your router's DHCP settings.

Also note that in either case the `.local` DNS resolution is happening via [mDNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS).